# Homepage routing problem with $this->pathConfig->getDefaultPath()

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, home-page, routing

I'm currently running a Multistore Magento 2 site, I have 4 websites configured, 2 of which have multiple URL's to access the site.

As a case example I have:

```
domain-a.com
www.domain-a.com
domain-a.co.uk
www.domain-a.co.uk
```

all mapped to the correct store run_code and run_type in index.php

When I access the site using domain-a.com or [www.domain-a.com](http://www.domain-a.com) I can see the homepage. All other categories/pages also work. This is true for every category/page for domain-a.co.uk with the exception of the homepage.

Accessing the homepage results in the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, null given in /home/customer/www/DOMAIN.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php:182
Stack trace:
#0 /home/customer/www/DOMAIN.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(182): explode('/', NULL)
#1 /home/customer/www/DOMAIN.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(165): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->parseRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#2 /home/customer/www/DOMAIN.co.uk/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/App/Router/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /home/customer/www/DOMAIN.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(95): Magento\Backend\App\Router\Interceptor->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/customer/www/DOMAIN.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): in /home/customer/www/DOMAIN.co.uk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php on line 182
```

Tracing this error back, I can see the method **$this->pathConfig->getDefaultPath()** within **vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php** is actually returning null for the request, attempts to add fall-back logic to use values like "cms_index_index" result in displaying the admin login for the default store view, so I suspect somewhere that the request being made for the homepage is being misinterpreted.

I've run a complete cache clean, cleaned my cloudflare cache as well and have also re-compiled and rebuilt the static cache, but nothing I try seems to fix the problem.

I've added the following code to the method as a test:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
echo $state->getAreaCode(); //frontend or adminhtml or webapi_rest
```

Confusingly, the AreaCode returns as "adminhtml"

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was in vendor/magento/framework/App/Arealist.php there is an issue with compatibility with my hosts custom PHP framework which needed resolving.